# Reading Data From MS Excel in .net

Tags: c#, excel, ado.net

I have written a piece of code that reads excel data in data table through ado.net. Now i have seen a strange behavior, That the column data type in ms excel is specified as general, but if the 1st row of the excel of that particular column contains some text, ado.net is unable to read numbers in that particular column and if 1st row contains some numeric information ado.net is unable to read textual data of that particular column. here is the code i am using to read data from excel.

```
    string excelConString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;
                                Data Source=D:\A.xls;
                                Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;""";
    var oleDbConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConString);

    var cmd = oleDbConnection.CreateCommand();

    cmd.CommandText = "select * from [WorkSheet$] where ID>=1500";

    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    da.Fill(dt);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards
Ahsan Iqbal

Comment: Have you tried adding MAXSCANROWS=0 to your extended properties in the connection string?

Answer (score 0):

change your connectionstring to

```
string excelConString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;
                          Data Source=D:\A.xls;
                          Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text"""
```

Comment: make HDR=NO - that should help